# save multiple image views as a single file

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-sdcard

In my application , one Relative Layout has totally **three ImageView()**'s . I want to save all the three imageviews as a single .png file to the device storage on a single button click.

My code:

Layout XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/make" >

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:src="@drawable/am0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Save Meme"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/wt" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Activity Code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.sm);

    main1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    top = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.top);
    down = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.down);

    Bundle rec = getIntent().getExtras();

    int rec1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ams0");
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) rec.getParcelable("bm0");
    Bitmap bmp1 = (Bitmap) rec.getParcelable("bm1");


    main1.setImageResource(rec1);
    top.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    down.setImageBitmap(bmp1);


}
```

How do I save the image views as a file ?

Comment: This should be something like a collage?

Comment: No it is not a collage , just an Image with the title at the top imageview and Description at bottom imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `Сanvas`

```
Bitmap mainBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)main1.getDrawable()).getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true), 1, 1, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true), 1, 1, null);

OutputStream os = null;
try {
      os = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/myImages.png");
      mainBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os);
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How to draw bitmap for bmp . I used canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 1, 1, null);    Is this correct?

Comment: But when I use this , the app throws an exception

Comment: use this `canvas.drawBitmap(bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true), 1, 1, null);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68559/discussion-between-it-assistors-and-sorryformyenglish).