# Image Edit SDK for Android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, adobe, aviary

I'm working on a project that requires taking pictures and putting stickers on that photo. From what I understand this requires 3 main actions:
 1. User should be able to resize the sticker.
 2. User should be able to rotate the sticker.
 3. And once done, the whole thing should be merged into a single image.

I'm having a really hard time starting this since I simply don't know where I should start. Should I find, or ever write my own code to do the above, or maybe try to use existing projects (but I was not able to find any open-source ones).

I've heard about Aviary, but it was recently purchased by Adobe, and it is now part of the Creative Cloud, which is quite vague regarding the price, if there is any.

Where should I start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Resizing** the image add two buttons one for increasing the image size and the other for decreasing . Then in the set an **onClickListener()** for that buttons.
Inside that function first get the dimensions of the image using **getWidth()** and **getHeight()** , then use **setWidth()** and **setHeight()** to change the size.

for **Rotatin**g the sticker refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle)

After all these things use a canvas to save the sticker and image as a single file . for doing this refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878619/save-multiple-image-views-as-a-single-file).

In future do not combine all your queries in a single question.

Answer (score 3):

We at Img.ly have released an image editing SDK for Android as part of our PhotoEditorSDK product suite.
Users can resize rotate and adjust stickers out of the box and you can also [add your own stickers and assets](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/android/customization#adding-or-removing-stickers).

You can find a demo application [here](https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-android-demo). You can use the library for free in your open source projects, but there is a license fee for commercial applications.

Answer (score 0):

I use these libraries and plugins in my projects
for cropping an image use this : [Cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper)

for rotating an image you can use this: [PhotoProcessing](https://github.com/lightbox/PhotoProcessing)

and at the end you can get the whole image in to a single image-view

Comment: PhotoProcessing seems to be no longer under development. Does it still work?